# ssh unable to connect from external

Tags: 18.04

I have installed Ubuntu 18.04 for personal use and few weeks ago I was able to connect from both internal and external IP. When I noticed others trying to access, I did disable access using iptables command.

I did use iptables ACCEPT on port 22 and now I am unable to connect using external IP, however ssh internal_ip works.

Port forwarding is setup in router to allow port 22 to Ubuntu IP. This is also seen when I run ***tcptraceroute external_ip***

**ip a** # shows expected internal IP

***tcptraceroute external_ip*** # shows router IP and Ubuntu Internal IP
when logged in with Internal IP /var/log/auth.log # shows "Accepted.."

Used this command to allow port 22

**sudo /sbin/iptables -I INPUT -p tcp -m tcp --dport 22 -j ACCEPT**

**iptables -L**

```
Chain INPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination         
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere             tcp dpt:ssh
```

**ufw status**
Status: inactive

/var/log/auth.log shows log when connected from internal IP. There is no log when trying to connect from external IP.

**ssh -vvv user@externalip**

```
OpenSSH_7.6p1 Ubuntu-4ubuntu0.3, OpenSSL 1.0.2n  7 Dec 2017
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh/ssh_config
debug1: /etc/ssh/ssh_config line 19: Applying options for *
debug2: resolving "external-ip" port 22
debug2: ssh_connect_direct: needpriv 0
debug1: Connecting to external-ip [external-ip] port 22.
```

** sudo service ssh status **

```
Active: active (running)
```

Please let me know what else I can check and also any tips when providing details. I have searched many posts and I could not narrow down issue.

Few weeks ago when I noticed several attempts to machine, I did install fail2ban with jail.local, let me know if details required.

I am getting familiar with iptables which I feel is not letting through.

The router is configured to forward to 192.168.1.115 port 22, please suggest how to forward using iptables.

I am updating with some other iptables I tried, I did flush all rules
with iptables -F

**sudo iptables -A INPUT -p tcp --dport 22 -m conntrack --ctstate NEW,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT**

I got the interface using
**ip -4 addr show scope global**

**ip route show | grep default**

**sudo iptables -A FORWARD -i wlp5s0  -p tcp --syn --dport 22 -m conntrack --ctstate NEW -j ACCEPT**

**nmap 192.168.1.115**

```
PORT     STATE SERVICE
22/tcp   open  ssh
```

**nmap external_ip**

```
PORT     STATE    SERVICE
22/tcp   filtered ssh
```

Comment: I used https://www.canyouseeme.org/ to confirm external IP and port is open.

Comment: What exact iptables command did you use? Without knowing what you typed, we can't tell you what you did wrong.

Comment: sudo /sbin/iptables -I INPUT -p tcp -m tcp --dport 22 -j ACCEPT